# Visual Studio 2017: Project is out of date with error (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 Professional on Windows 10, solution with 47 projects targeting .NET 4.5.2.

VS always rebuilds many projects in my solution even if unchanged and up to date.  I this "very informative" message:

```
1>Project 'A' is not up to date. Error (0x80004005). 
1>------ Build started: Project: A, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Project 'B' is not up to date. Error (0x80004005). 
2>------ Build started: Project: B, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

I cannot see any .suo files in the solution.  Some projects in the solution are C# and others are VB.NET.  However, as I was typing this, I notice that it is the C# projects only that throw the 0x80004005 error and compel rebuild.

Please help me solve this weird problem.

Thanks.

Comment: 0x80004005 = generic fail/error code.VS rebuilds the solution [because of this issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/05/12/msbuild-unnecessary-rebuilds-because-of-generated-assemblyattributes-cs/)

Comment: Hi - I remapped the assemblyattributes.cs to the project's obj\debug folder.  Does not resolve the 0x80004005 errors, even after reboots and even reinstalling VS 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

In the .csproj file, there was this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" **ToolsVersion="12.0"**>
```

But if you change it to this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" **ToolsVersion="Current"**>
```

[ ** Highlighting mine]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error 0x80004005 on loading.
And all that was needed was to run build -> clean code solution

Answer (score -2):

I find the following link may describe the reason of throwing the error and the correspond solution.

[You may receive error code 0x80004005 or other error codes when you try to start a Windows XP-based computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/914232/you-may-receive-error-code-0x80004005-or-other-error-codes-when-you-tr)

You can try it from the link.

Comment: It is actually Windows XP based system related, not Visual Studio related.